# Is it possible to include a list in a DbSet?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

**WCF Service Demo Code**

```
public List<Message> GetMessages(string userAddress)
{
    return this.projectContext.Messages.Include("Contacts").ToList();
}
```

**Message Class**

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

When i try to consume that method on client side i get the next error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you make the Contact an Entity, you can include the contact entity in your context and map it via a foreign key to from Message Entity.